# How to update users with Socket.io when a database has been updated?

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, socket.io, knex.js

We are putting together a webgame where you can play rock, paper, scissors with someone else in real time. Game information (like what the player threw, their score, username, etc.) gets inserted into Sqlite3 when that player makes a move.

We need Socket.io to communicate from the server back to the users when certain conditions are met in the database. To let P1 know what P2 threw and if their hand won, for example.

Everything I've seen online so far is either a loop that periodically checks the database (like long-polling) or including socket.io on each individual function that updates the database.

I feel like I'm missing the point here and that I've overlooked something basic. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Implementing `socket.io` in your database update logic might be the way to go. Can you show some code on where and how you update the database? You might even be able to do whole games/sessions in memory and only persist scores for example. Your scenario offers a wide variety of architectural possibilities.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful: [Data Change Notification Callbacks](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html).

Comment: Socket.io would be the easiest solution, you need something to broadcast events to all your clients using web-sockets. It's fairly easy and implementing it for rock, paper, scissors would not be that complicated. If you don't need to use sql then I would also check out [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), which is a real time database that uses sockets as well.